# Call function in python module in temporary context?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

I'm currently extending a project that does not implement any classes. I need to call a function from one module that has side effects on global variables in that module. If I simply import the module and call the function, this has side effects on the rest of the program, which I don't want.

Solutions that I thought about so far:

1. Modify the module so that it's a class: This would break compatibility with the existing code which I want to avoid.
2. Save the state of the class at the beginning of the method and restore it at the end: This could have side effects because there is multi threading involved.
3. Copy the whole module: Probably the best option, but I want to avoid code duplication.

Is there a better option to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

This situation sounds like classical XY problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Assume that there exists a module, and that module has a function, and that function is hard coded to change state that is maintained with module level variables.

In this situation there probably does not exist any sensible way to programmatically avoid the function changing the module level variables, unless the function explicitly supports assigning custom context.

You can create ad-hoc solution that fixes the problem for a known variable but general purpose solution sounds impractical when comparing to restructuring the code.

Without knowing more details it is hard to suggest anything specifically, except for restructuring the module.

Some options:

- Use classes
- Make the function support custom context by providing locals() from elsewhere
- Make a clone of function without side effects
- Save state of known module level variables, call the function, restore state

Interestingly enough, you can automate the last option if you can be sure that the side effects exists within a known scope. Using dir(your_module) provides programmatical access.

Ultimately I think the problem in and of itself is proof that you should consider restructuring. This is coming from someone who is hell bent on the ability to abuse python by doing stuff like walking up the callstack to change variables in parent-of-parent-of-parent-of-parent to force program state. I even made debugger capable of doing that (https://github.com/hirsimaki-markus/SEAPIE)

Yet I still think breaking compability and restructing is the more sensible long term solution. Of the ad-hoc solutions, I would suggest creating side-effectless versions of the necessary functions.